# I need a case to get value from another table when join returns null value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

First just take a look from my image

The tables:
[image]

I need when join doesnt find anything to get the value from my second table

How can i do that?
Here is my code:

```
select * from  GridHour
select * from  Grid
SELECT a.HistoryID1,a.CustomerID1,CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), b.Hour,108),a.Text1,a.Text2,a.HistoryID2,a.CustomerID2 from Grid a full join GridHour b on a.AppointmentHour=b.hour
```

Comment: Don't just dump query here and think others will understand what you are trying to do.  Explain what you are trying to do.  Give table structure, sample input, expected output.  Then maybe, someone will help you.  Learn how to ask question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the 2 joins and use the isNull function like this:

*If the first value is null, take the other value like in the example

```
select * from  GridHour
select * from  Grid
SELECT 
   a.HistoryID1, 
   a.CustomerID1, 
   CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),isnull(b.Hour,c.Hour),108), -- Here put the isnull function
   a.Text1, 
   a.Text2, 
   a.HistoryID2, 
   a.CustomerID2  
from Grid a 
   full join GridHour b 
      on a.AppointmentHour=b.hour
   left join Grid c
      on a.HistoryID=b.GridID -- Not sure if this is the link
```